Seeking Insight into iparse.io Functionality Within Salesforce
Could someone kindly explain to me how iparse.io operates internally within Salesforce, or provide a reference to documentation? I have reviewed the documentation available at the following link (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000GvDr3UAF&tab=d), but I'm struggling to fully understand its Salesforce schema, design flow, etc

Since it is solution offered by Vesium Ltd, it will make more sense to ask them about it. Asked questions are not something that is part of salesforce platform, but rather an extension for it, developed by ISV

Can you kindly suggest me the platform for that?

I am not sure if I understand your question

Could you suggest a platform where I can inquire about the details of iparse.io? I couldn't find assistance from Vesium Ltd. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me understand its mechanism.
